# Alternatives to word to vector embedding

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I'm just curious are there some alternative techniques to word 2 vector representation? So words/phrases/sentences are not represented as vectors but have a different form. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Yes, of course: this is the traditional bag of word representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you talk about vector embeddings or "word 2 vector representation" (word2vec was the first software to train word embeddings). It's important to understand that not all vectors are embeddings:

- Embeddings are short vectors made of real numbers, they were invented around 2010. There are many different types of embeddings, i.e. methods to train the embeddings from a corpus: word2vec, Glove, Elmo, Fasttext, Bert...
- Before this, people were also using vectors representing a "bag of words": one-hot-encoding for a single word, frequency count or TFIDF for a sentence/document. These vectors are long and sparse, i.e. they usually contain a lot of zeros.

These are the most common word representation methods, but there are potentially other alternatives. For example, in [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) the words are nodes in a graph and relations between words are represented as edges.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've finally got some clarity about it.

Answer (score -2):

<s>I researched this question and looks like I realized that there are many word representations.</s>

1. Dictionary lookup
2. One-hot encoding
3. Distributional representation

   a. Frequency counts

   b. Word2Vec(Skip-Gram and CBOW)

   c. GloVe
4. Elmo
5. Subword

@Erwan provided more correct answer above

Comment: You are confusing things: 'Dictionary lookup' is not a word representation; word2vec, Glove, Elmo and subwords are different word embeddings representations. The one which is correct is in your list is One-hot encoding, i.e. the good old bag of words.

Comment: @Erwan: I wanted to know how else words can be represented other than as vectors(if at all). You prompted to me that it is bag of words. Then I read about bag of words and figured out that it is still vector representation(e.g. https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-bag-words-model/)  So, I thought my question is incorrect. Everything is always a vector. It might be correctly to think about embedding representations. I read this article https://towardsdatascience.com/word-representation-in-natural-language-processing-part-i-e4cd54fed3d4 and answered. Sorry for confusing

Comment: ok, I tried to explain things better in another answer.